# Unauthorized when trying to allow nodes to join a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I had a two node cluster in which one was master and another slave. It was running from the last 26 days. Today i tried to remove a node using kubeadm reset and add it again and kubelet was not able to start

```
cni.go:171] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
The binary conntrack is not installed, this can cause failures in network connection cleanup.
server.go:376] Version: v1.10.2
feature_gate.go:226] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
plugins.go:89] No cloud provider specified.
server.go:233] failed to run Kubelet: cannot create certificate signing request: Unauthorized
```

while the join command is successful

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
[WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
Suggestion: go get github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-tools/cmd/crictl
[preflight] Starting the kubelet service
[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "aaaaa:6443"
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://aaaaa:6443"
[discovery] Requesting info from "https:/aaaaaa:6443" again to validate TLS against the pinned public key
[discovery] Cluster info signature and contents are valid and TLS certificate validates against pinned roots, will use API Server
[discovery] Successfully established connection with API Server "aaaa:6443"

This node has joined the cluster:

Certificate signing request was sent to master and a response
was received.
The Kubelet was informed of the new secure connection details.

Run 'kubectl get nodes' on the master to see this node join the cluster.
```

IMO the log failed to run Kubelet: cannot create certificate signing request: Unauthorized is the source of the problem, but I am do not know how it is coming and how to fix it.

TIA. I can give more details but I am not sure what all I shall give

Comment: Looks like network subsystem is not installed or somehow broken.

Could you provide brief description of your environment setup, `kubeadm` commands sequence that you've run to create cluster, and output of the commands: `kubectl get nodes`, `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

Comment: @The_Lost_Avatar : Do you have solution on this ???